# Android Web App - Instant Messenger

Tags: android, web-applications, instant-messaging

I would like to build a web app that uses Instant Messaging. Would anyone have any pointers as to how I might go about doing this? I am quite clueless as to how to even begin...

Any guidance on what this would involve would be great!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is a web based instant messenger really the way you need to go. There are ample amounts of IM native apps that support running in the background, access to contacts and more importantly. Push notifications. What Is the reason for it being web based?

Comment: Hi gcoulby, I am doing this for a uni assignment and the requirement is that I make a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Start reading about XMPP/Jabber and aSmack library

Google has on open source code for this can be found in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/)

Comment: Thanks Brontok. This may seem a silly question but it seems that Jabber (Smack Library) uses Java. So I was wondering would I be able to implement this if I were making a web app using HTML/CSS/Javascript?

Comment: @Giri, no difference, really. The library would be used on the server-side, while the HTML/CSS/JS aspects are on the client-sides. You can use whatever you want on the server-side--be it Java or PHP or whatever.